# Proving a function is increasing in $n$.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I am trying to prove that the function $\frac{n}{2n+1}$, defined for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, decreases in $\mathbb{N}$. I attempted it by induction, but I'm not convinced that I fully need induction. Why can I not prove that for an arbitrary $n$, $f(n) \leq f(n+1)$ and deduce that, because $n$ was arbitrary, this holds for all $n$? The only thing left out would be the base case, but. I'm not fully sure why I need it here.

Regardless, here is my attempt at the induction:

> Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(n) = \frac{n}{2n+1}$. We prove by induction on $n$ that $f$ is increasing in $n$. If $n = 1$, we notice that
> \begin{align*}
> f(1) = \frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{2}{5} = f(2). 
> \end{align*}
> Suppose inductively that we have $f(n) \leq f(n+1)$ for some $n \geq 1$. So we have
> $\frac{n}{2n+1} \leq \frac{n+1}{2n+3}$. First, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{n+1}{2n+3} \leq \frac{n+3}{2n+3}.
> \end{align*}
> Furthermore, $2n + 5 \geq 2n + 3$, so $\frac{1}{2n + 5} \leq \frac{1}{2n+3}$, so $\frac{n+3}{2n + 3} \leq \frac{n+3}{2n+5}$. Therefore, it follows that
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{n+1}{2n+3} \leq \frac{n+3}{2n+3} \leq \frac{n+3}{2n + 5} = \frac{(n+2) + 1}{2(n+2) + 1}, 
> \end{align*}
> so $f(n+1) \leq f(n+2)$, which closes the induction

Comment: No need for induction. Show that $\frac n {2n+1} \leq \frac {n+1} {2n+3}$ directly by cross-multiplying.

Comment: Showing $f(n)\leq f(n+1)$, then appealing to $n$ being arbitrary would be best. To be fully rigorous you would close it with: $\\$ if $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ are such that $n\leq m$ we have $$f(n)\leq f(n+1) \leq ... \leq f(m-1) \leq f(m) $$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is what I thought, though can you explain what exactly the difference between this and induction is and why it isn't necessary here?

Comment: Supspoe you are asked to prove tht $n <n+1$ for all positive integers $n$. Would you use induction ot just say it is obvious? Wjaht about $1+n^{2}<(1+n)^{2}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: It makes sense in those cases to just prove it for an arbitrary $n$ and then conclude it's true for all $n$. But my thought process is, "why not just do that for all proofs involving natural numbers and why use induction ever?" which leads me to believe that I really don't understand the real distinction.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we can directly check $f(n)< f(n+1)$ that is

$$\frac{n}{2n+1}<\frac{n+1}{2n+3} \iff 2n^2+3n<2n^2+3n+1 \iff0<1$$

which is true.

Comment: Is there a reason we don't need induction here, though? I'm not sure I understand the difference in the proof methodologies.

Comment: @BradG. I'll try to add something on that.

Answer (score 0):

We avoid using induction in this approach.

You have $$f(n)=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$
Hence, $$f(n)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2n+1}}{2}$$
Now, as $n$ increases, $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ decreases and hence,
$f(n)$ increases.

Comment: Why are we allowed to avoid induction, though? I'm not sure I understand the difference here.

Comment: We may avoid using an approach(be it induction or something else) if we can manage solving the problem using some other approach. No approach works in every situation. We have to decide what approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{n}{2n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{2n}{2n+1} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{2n+1 - 1}{2n+1} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \right)$

Since $ \dfrac{1}{2n+1} $ decreases with increasing $n$, then $ \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \right)$ is increasing with $n$, thus $\dfrac{n}{2n+1} $ increases with increasing $n$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by induction would express that if $f$ is increasing at $n$, then $f$ is increasing at $n+1$, or

$$\frac n{2n+1}<\frac{n+1}{2n+3}\implies\frac{n+1}{2n+3}<\frac{n+2}{2n+5},$$

which can be rewritten as

$$-\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+3)}<0\implies-\frac1{(2n+3)(2n+5)}<0.$$

This proposition is true, but a little nonsense as both members are tautologies.

Answer (score 0):

As Kavi Rama Murthy and "user" point out, you don't need induction to show that $f(n + 1) \geq f(n)$.  But (according to the usual definition of "increasing"), you need to show more than that; that for any $m$ and $n$ with $n \geq m$, $f(n) \geq f(m)$.  And to derive that rigorously from $f(n + 1) \geq f(n)$, you do need induction (even though the inference is intuitively obvious).

But you can show $n \geq m \ \Rightarrow f(n) \geq f(m)$ without induction.  GeometryLover and ilovemath deduce that from the premise that the sequence $n \mapsto \frac{1}{2n + 1}$ is decreasing.  More directly, we have
\begin{align*}
f(n) - f(m)
&= \frac{n}{2n + 1} - \frac{m}{2m + 1}\\
&= \frac{n - m}{(2m + 1)(2n +1)}\\
&> 0,
\end{align*}
so $f(n) > f(m)$, whenever $n > m$.